# Automatically create a json file which lists all images in a directory?

Tags: php, json, file

I have a directory "files" on my webspace. In this directory are png-images, which may change frequently.

The filenames need to be stored in a json file.

Is there a way to automatically create a json file which lists all images in a directory in the following way:

```
art_showWindow({"art":[
{"href":"http://www.domain.example/files/art_noveau_1.png","title":"Art Noveau 1"},
{"href":"http://www.domain.example/files/art_noveau_5.png","title":"Art Noveau 5"},
{"href":"http://www.domain.example/files/art_noveau_23.png","title":"Art Noveau 23"},
]});
```

The title can of course just be a repetition of the filename if the above is too difficult.

Is this somehow possible?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not a magical native PHP function that does exactly that, although it would not be terribly surprising.

Since writing the script for you is not going to help you learn things much, I think it's best to point out a number of tools to use for this challenge.

First of all, you want to find all the PNG files in a directory; To list all the files (and directories) in a directory, use [scandir($directory)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php). From there on, you can use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to iterate over the returned array, and only stick the PNG files in a new array.

Since the output of scandir does not make files and directories discernible, you might want to run [is_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) on the results to make sure you only get the files.

You can then use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to retrieve the extension and base name (filename without its extension, labeled 'filename' in the output of pathinfo) of a current file. You will need the extension to figure out whether the file is a PNG (and thus one to add to your new array).

Once you've iterated over the scandir array and have created an array with PNG file names, you can start building your final array. You'll want to start another [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop, in which you prepend 'http://www.domain.example/files/' to the file names, and do some magic to convert the file name to a title. You want to array to be structured like this:

```
$art = array(    
    array(
        'href' => $full_url,
        'title' => $title
    ),
    array(
        'href' => $full_url,
        'title' => $title
    ),
    // etc
);
```

To get the title, I'd go with this seemingly complex one-liner:

```
$title = ucwords( // Give words an upper case first letter
    str_replace('_', ' ', //replace underscores by spaces
        substr($filename, 0, (strlen($filename) - 4) //strip .png extension
    )
);
```

Once the foreach loop is done, you'll have a fully populate art array. To convert this to JSON, you simple use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like so:

```
$output = json_encode(array('art' => $art));
```

You mention you want to save it as a json file; Are you sure you don't just want PHP to output the JSON?

Either way, to save the file, easy enough, [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) will do the job.

If you just want PHP to output it, you'll want to set the Content-Type HTTP header to application/json: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` and then simply echo the $output.

Hope that helps!

(And I realise that this took more effort than just writing you a snippet of code, but at least you'll still have to do a little think work to accomplish it. Good luck!