# Accessing Web Server, Get All Files In Directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to access a web server and get all of the files in a directory, but only using a link to the directory, not links to the individual files. Is there anyway to do this? NSFileManager has a getURLsToFilesInDirectory or something to that effect but it doesn't appear to work on servers. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I dont think this is posible without any server side code.

Comment: Do you mean like setting up a SQL database on the server and then accessing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is posible without any server side code. 
I suggest to write a code Read files from directory in php and list out entries in a json file

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044441/automatically-create-a-json-file-which-lists-all-images-in-a-directory) will help you to do that